# React Router in app served from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: reactjs, react-router, google-cloud-storage

I'd like to serve a React app from static file storage (Google Cloud Storage, AWS equivalent is S3).

In the past I've only ever deployed React apps to an NGINX server (or in an NGINX container) where I can configure all requests to point to `index.html`, regardless of the requested path, so that React Router can handle the routing on the client side.

I'm struggling to understand how this would work in static file storage, by just running `npm run build` and uploading the built app to Cloud Storage.

Example: To my understanding, if you request `<domain>/profile`, it will look for a file named "`profile`" in static file storage and then return the storage provider's 404 page if it doesn't exist. But I want this to be handled by React Router, which means this request still technically returns the `index.html` page, then the JavaScript on the client side looks at the URL and renders either the profile page component or a soft 404 page component which I can customise from within my React app.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so 6 months down the track, I now have the answer and I'm sharing it to help anyone who's stuck like I was.

When configuring a GCS bucket to serve a static site, you are given the choice to choose which file it should serve as the index page, and which file to serve on a 404. Turns out, you can pretty easily achieve client-side routing on a Single Page App (with any JavaScript framework) by configuring the bucket to point all traffic that would return a 404 page to the same `index.html` file. This way, it will still render the "single page" that holds all the client-side routing logic, and the path it looks at will be in the URL!

TLDR; Set `index.html` as your custom 404 page.